# I have a simple code works fine on localhost, but does not work on the real server

Tags: php

I have a simple code as following:

```
$fileName = "banned_sites.txt";
$fileContent = file_get_contents($fileName);
$banned_sites = explode(',', $fileContent);
if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $banned_sites)) {
    echo "Yes it is <br/><br/>";
} else {
    echo "No it does not <br/><br/>";
}
```

Also the following is the content of `banned_sites.txt`, also it's permission 644 and I tried also 755.

```
localhost,
yahoo.com,
mysite.net
```

When print the array gives me `Array ( [0] => localhost [1] => yahoo.com [2] => mysite.net )`, and this proves that the file is readable.
Also no any error message appear.

Now I want to know, why the previous code work fine on `localhost`, but on `real web server` does not work and always gives me `No it does not` message .

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this? Did you check to see if you can open the file properly? Did you see if the array is populated? Did you inspect the values? Did you remove the `@` to see if an error thrown?

Comment: and did you consider to check if the txt file is in the root.

Comment: @rockStar: the text file beside the php page.

Comment: is your website mbawb.net or yahoo.com?

Comment: @John Conde: `Did you check to see if you can open the file properly` -> yes, no problem , `Did you see if the array is populated` -> yes , `Did you remove the @ to see if an error thrown` -> yes, no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I see in your file each host is followed by `,\n` but in your code you are exploding on `,` so at the beginning of each string (except localhost) you have `\n` that you don't see in the array but php sees when comparing strings. try trimming your array values.

Try this before your if statement

```
 $banned_sites = array_map("trim", $banned_sites);
```

Comment: Thank you very much on your note, the problem was `\n`, now everything is works fine.